# How do I automatically run a binary in the background using Emacs Lisp when in a particular major mode?

Tags: emacs, purescript

I would like to automatically run the [purescript language server](https://github.com/nwolverson/purescript-language-server) binary in the background when Emacs loads a `.purs` PureScript file in PureScript mode.  Is there an easy way to do this using Emacs Lisp in my `init.el` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun my-program ()
  (message "Start to run my-program")
  ;; Replace with your binary.
  (shell-command "pwd"))
(add-hook 'purescript-mode-hook #'my-program)
```

Comment: I am getting a "Shell command failed with code 1 and no output" error.  Here is my init.el code:
       (defun start-els ()
            (message "Starting elm-language-server")
              (shell-command "elm-language-server"))
(add-hook 'elm-mode-hook #'start-els)  

 However, when I open up eshell manually and run `$ elm-language-server` (trying it with an elm mode as well), it starts with no problem.  Any ideas why?

Comment: This worked for me, I needed to add the "&" at the end of the shell-command string to make it run asynchronously.

This is the final version that worked:

(add-hook 'elm-mode-hook (lambda ()
      (message "Starting the elm-language-server in the background")
       (shell-command "elm-language-server &")))